# Javascript button error

Tags: javascript, custom-button

I am creating JavaScript button for creating a new record of a custom object my code looks as follow.

```
{!REQUIRESCRIPT("/soap/ajax/29.0/connection.js")}
{!REQUIRESCRIPT("/support/console/31.0/integration.js")} 

var newFollowUp= new sforce.SObject("Follow_up__c");
newFollowUp.name = 'New FollowUp';
newFollowUp.Case__C = {!Case.Id};
var result = sforce.connection.create([newFollowUp]);

if(result[0].getBoolean("success")){
window.location = "/" + result[0].id + "/e";
}else{
alert('Could not create record '+result);
}
```

when I click on this button I get error saying

> Invalid or unexpected token

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following changes will work for you.

Instead of using `window.location`, use `window.location.href` to navigate to Edit page.

```
{!REQUIRESCRIPT("/soap/ajax/29.0/connection.js")}
{!REQUIRESCRIPT("/support/console/31.0/integration.js")} 

var newFollowUp= new sforce.SObject("Follow_up__c");
newFollowUp.name = 'New FollowUp';
newFollowUp.Case__C = "{!Case.Id}";
var result = sforce.connection.create([newFollowUp]);

if(result[0].success == 'true'){
    window.location.href = "/" + result[0].id + "/e"; //for console use srcUp("/" + result[0].id + "/e")
}else{
    alert('Could not create record '+result);
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer Santanu. I see this button creates the record now but doesn't open the edit screen. I have window.location = "/" + result[0].id + "/e";

Comment: you have to use `window.location.href`, updated my ans

Comment: Hmm I have changed that with href still no luck.

Comment: whats `result[0].id` is retunring?

Comment: I have checked that , `window.location.href = "/" + '{!Case.Id}' + "/e";` is working fine for me at my DE, so it should work syntaxually

Comment: yes it is returning value. could this be because I am in service console?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/60076/discussion-between-aman-and-santanu-boral).

Comment: result[0].id returns a0TK0000007Vq4wMAC

Comment: Thanks Santanu,Yes that was the problem as I was in service console. So I have added var url and passed that to srcUp(url); . Which solved my problem. Thank you